# Выравнивание по центру меню

Tags: html, css

Помогите выровнять css меню по центру. Все перепробовал, нечего не выходит, может у Вас выйдет. [Вот код](http://jsfiddle.net/qgxUA/).

```
.hovermenu ul {
    font: 20px verdana;
    padding - left: 0;
    margin - left: 0;
    height: 20px;
}

.hovermenu ul li {
    list - style: none;
    display: inline;
}

.hovermenu ul li a {
    padding: 9px 0.5em;
    text - decoration: none;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    background - color: transparent;
    border: px solid transparent;
}

.hovermenu ul li a: hover {
    background - color: #1E90FF;

}

html>body .hovermenu ul li a:active{ /* эффект при наведении мыши */
border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Код поправьте сначала, jsfiddle вам красным подсвечивает, что не все в порядке с разметкой. отделите css, html и js (если есть) - там есть поля ввода для каждого из них. И после этого укажите что вы перепробовали.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qgxUA/1/
Отделил

ставил тег centr, пробовал в разные места ставить. Оно только немного в бок отодвигается

Answer (score 3):

Плохо отделили. float:left - для `a` лишнее, у вас есть уже `display:inline` для `li`, все будет в строчку и так. Надо после этого отцентрировать содержимое `ul`, добавить:

```
.hovermenu {text-align:center}
```

upd. или лучше:

```
.hovermenu ul {text-align:center}
```

см. [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/QqhUg/)

Answer (score 0):

Немного исправил. Вот что получилось. С вертикальным выравниванием, думаю справитесь =)

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">.hovermenu ul{

font: 20px verdana;
padding-left: 0;
margin-left: 0;
height: 20px;
}

.hovermenu ul li{
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}

.hovermenu ul li a{
padding: 9px 0.5em;
text-decoration: none;

color: black;
background-color: transparent;
border: px solid transparent;
}

.hovermenu ul li a:hover{
background-color:#1E90FF;

}

html>body .hovermenu ul li a:active{ /* эффект при наведении мыши */
border-style: solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120531/pbb8FT9l.jpg);background-repeat:repeat-x repeat-x">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (ВСЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕ.psd) -->

<head>

<body style="color:Yellow; background-color:#FFFFFF "><div class="hovermenu">
<table style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    <tr><td style="text-align:center;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Мои лоты</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Добавить в избранное</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Задать вопрос</a></li>
</ul>
        </td></tr>
 </table>
</div>

<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Если не секрет, что изменили?

Comment: шикарно. из серии "css - фигня, таблицы - наше все!". -1.